# Covering images from both sides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this menu, that (when you hover over an icon) makes the icon bigger. What I tried to achieve is, to have it display correctly from both sizes, which doesn't quite work. It only works from the left side, because of the unordered list, but is there a way to make it work from both sides? (basically so the icon covers the one to the right and the one to the left without pushing it). I have this:
HTML:

```
    <!-- START OF THE MENU !-->
<div class="menu-outer" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;;">
    <div class="menu-icon">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
         <center>
         <a href="goolag_games.html"><img class="icon" src="games.png"></a>     
         <a href="index.html"><img class="icon" src="home.png"></a>      
         <a href="contact.html"><img class="icon" src="contact.png"></a>
         <a href="wai.html"><img class="icon" src="wai.png"></a>
         <a href="wita.html"><img class="icon" src="wita.png"></a>
         </center>
        </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
<a class="menu-close" onClick="return true">
    <div class="menu-icon">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
</a>
<!-- END OF THE MENU!-->
```

CSS:

```
.icon{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -5;
}
.icon:hover{
    width: 155px;
    margin: -15px -22px -15px -13px;
}
.menu{
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Thanks for all the help.
If anything, it's all uploaded here (in the right corner menu):
http://goolag.pw/delete2.html

Comment: So you want the icon to stay on the right side when it changes?

Comment: In .icon:hover you could set `position: relative;` or something and then give that icon a higher z-index.

Comment: I want the icon to stay where it is, just kinda zoom in as it does already, but make it so it covers the other icons (that are next to it) without pushing them around.

Comment: @TylerH - Tried that, doesn't change anything. Z-index doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: In the hover rule add `position: relative`. Also, for future questions it is much easier to help if you create an example with the fewest possible pieces to demonstrate your problem typically using something like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you'll need to use an `absolute`ly positioned element inside of your `relative inline-block`. leave the relative element set to your original height/ width and only adjust the sizing and positional offset of the `absolute` positioned element. This will allow you to place the icon(s) whereever you like without moving(juking) around the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
.icon{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
.icon:hover{
    z-index: 100;
}
```

By increasing the `z-index`, the hovered icon is moved up in the DOM-layer, and displayed above the other icons.

Comment: Gotta wait 2 minutes! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use z-index, but in order to do that, you need to add the element a positioning. I tried this and worked:

```
.menu a:hover{
  z-index: 150;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set all the images' `z-index` property to a negative value and when the image hovers, set it to a positive one. I don't know if this is a bug but that's how it behaves, take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BWHs/):

```
#one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}

#two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

If you set the first element's `z-index` to a `>0` value, it won't show over the second one until it's `z-index` is set to something `<0`.